# Checking if Token is already approved python

Tags: python, web3py, binance-smart-chain, binance-api-client

I have this code for checking if a token is already approved.
The problem is that I get 0 every time, even if I put in an approved token.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import json
import sys
from web3 import Web3

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print(web3.isConnected())


"0x3c7eeddcff188a8c36f1cac1b62958c6e0c27dea"  # G2 already approved
"0xcc5667333f5e997ac9f0c26d41b7dda65b2b675a"  # GloryDoge not approved

contract = "0x3c7eeddcff188a8c36f1cac1b62958c6e0c27dea"  # Contract
contract = web3.toChecksumAddress(contract)
abi = [
    {
        "constant": True,
        "inputs": [
            {"name": "_owner", "type": "address"},
            {"name": "_spender", "type": "address"},
        ],
        "name": "allowance",
        "outputs": [{"name": "", "type": "uint256"}],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
    },
]
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract, abi=abi)

_owner = web3.toChecksumAddress(MYADRESS)
_spender = web3.toChecksumAddress(
    "0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c"
)  # WBNB

x = contract.functions.allowance(_owner, _spender).call()

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine!

Insead of filling in the wbnb token address for _spender, you should give the address of the thing you gave the allowance to. For instance, the pancake router address "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E".

You can check which address you gave allowance to by looking at the approve transaction in bscscan.com

Click on "click to see more", and click on "Decode Input Data".

You will see the spender address that you approved.